# (Fuzzy) Compare screenshots not only by color values of pixels

Tags: java, image, image-processing, distance, fuzzy-comparison

I want to compare screenshots (stable and release) for different sites of a software (there are too many to ckeck this manually). The screenshots will be created within different automated seleneium acceptance-tests.

Now I want to compare (compare and create a diff-image) the screenshots in a useful way. At the moment the screenshots will be compared pixel by pixel (colors of the pixel). For fuzziness I calculate the Delta-E (Lab space and euclidean distance) of the colors.

For calculating the distance there are algorithms like AE, FUZZ, MAE, MEPP, MSE, NCC, PAE, PHASH, PSNR, RMSE and Perceptual Diff. Without to know each in detail, but all are based on the color of the pixels? What else...

Then there are other distance measures like euclidean and manhattan distance too. But these are based on colors too.

Can anyone tell me which of the mentioned is the best for the case of screenshot comparison? Or are there bether approaches? For example it would be great to distinguish between different elements (it would be more bad if a button is missing then when a input field is slightly moved). Or consider all elements are moved 1px. Then the image is completely different.

The big problem in my opinion is, that the screenshot has no semantic. Has anyone good ideas for my requirements? Maybe a combination with DOM, computed styles, template matching or edge detection is possible? Experiences?

PS I know about frameworks like PhantomCSS, Wraith etc. But I checked the code of the most. They use either ImageMagick or do a simple pixel based comparison.

Comment: Two questions: 1. What are the images in the screenshots - photos? diagrams? HTML tables? 2. What is the purpose in comparing the images - to see if a website has changed? To test browser compatibility?

Comment: Ohh sorry, the screenshots are from webpages of a software in different browsers. But the purpose is NOT to do a visual cross browser test. It should only compare a new release of a software against the old version. But with screenshots from the same browser.

Comment: Instead of seing a browser page as an amount of pixels you should see it as set of elements. Using image analysis you could detect elements (buttons, textfields, textareas, images and so forth) by its shape and color or presence of texture. Having the elements positions you could perform some triangularization and get the "page biometrics". If one element is added/removed/moved you could detect. Comparing two pages you will consider the number and type of elements and the relative distance between each other. Not simple, but feasible.

Comment: Can you provide more infos please?